# Is there an alternative widget to listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a messaging program for fun. I intend to use this with friends and family, so I want to treat it as I am making actual software that will be used by others.

After thinking about the future of the project, I realized that images, videos and gifs should be shared over the application, without having to lead to external sites like giphy (I don't mind embedding videos though).

Currently, I am using a Listbox to display the messages, but that comes with a lot of limitations. Mainly in presentation, no messaging programs select messages like a cell in a spreadsheet. But also in future functions, you cannot add an image to Listbox, you cannot add a video or gif (also you aren't technically adding planned things to the Listbox, just whatever data is sent to the client as I am using sockets).

In short, I need a widget that can share text, video (most standard formats like mp4), audio (mp3, wav, ogg, etc.) and images (jpg, png, gif). This widget also should be easy to use for my sort of program, which is just a messaging application.

If this very specific widget doesn't exist, then what could I do to fulfill the above instead?

Comment: use [canvas](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 How would I be able to use canvas in a way that updates the canvas each time a message is received? while also keeping the ability to scroll up to previous messages.

Comment: You can use a Text widget, it will be easier than a Canvas to put the content in (because of the lines). In a Text widget, you can embed images with `.image_create()` and any widget using `.window_create()` (https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html). You can also use tag bindings to create clickable links.